# Display text in number input (associated to value)

Tags: javascript, css, angular, html

Let's say I have a number input with only a few possible values like the following :

```
<label for="test" translate="entities.test"></label>
<input id="test" name="test" type="number" min="1" max="4" [(ngModel)]="model.test" class="form-control" [disabled]="isDisabled()" formControlName="test">
```

I wish to keep the numeric value but display some text for each value like :

"1 - High"

"2 - Medium"

"3 - Low"

"4 - Negligible"

Instead of just the number in the input.

Is this doable?

Or do I necessarily need to use a text input with a pattern restriction to limit the input to integers between 1 and 4 and then convert the value from text to number before sending it to my backend

Comment: It's a placeholder?

Comment: From what I understand you need a `select` here not a in `input`

Comment: Depends on where you want to display it ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the list attribute on the input like below

```html
<input id="test" name="test" type="number" min="1" max="4" [(ngModel)]="model.test" class="form-control" [disabled]="isDisabled()" formControlName="test" list="severity">
<datalist id="severity">
    <option value="1"> High</option>
    <option value="2"> Medium</option>
    <option value="3"> Low </option>
    <option value="4"> Negligible</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: I didn't go for this solution but this seems to be the closest from what I asked for, thanks !

Answer (score 3):

As you have only 4 distinct value, It's would better to use a `<select>`
The value and the text in a select option are totally independent
So it would look like:

```html
<select id="test" name="test" [(ngModel)]="model.test" class="form-control" [disabled]="isDisabled()" formControlName="test">
  <option value="1">1 - High</option>
  <option value="2">2 - Medium</option>
  <option value="3">3 - Low</option>
  <option value="4">4 - Negligible</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yea, That was my thought too, but I wanted to still be able to use the mouse wheel or the keyboard to input the value somehow, I will go with that solution if I can't find anothre way